# деплой проекта на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

загрузила проект на pythonanywhere - все нормально, все установилось. пробую зайти - пишет проблема с темплейтом.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /projects/

base.html
```

хотя локально все работает! вроде бы все нормально прописала,

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Comment: Для ответа на данный вопрос, хотелось бы конкретики, хотя бы на каком фреймворке написан проект.

Comment: джанго) я так понимаю что я что-то не прописала, потому что локально то все работает отлично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно указать Django, где искать ваш шаблон. Добавьте следующие строки в верхней части файла настроек, а затем установите DIRS в TEMPLATES. Пример:

```
import os

PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, 'template')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: большое спасибо, но это не сработало(( пишет ошибку все еще

Comment: все  сработало!!! огромное вам спасибо!!

Comment: Если удалось вам помочь, пожалуйста, пометьте ответ как правильный. Всего доброго!)